# add poster to audio in mediaelement.js

Tags: audio, mediaelement.js, poster

I want to add poster to mp3/audio in mediaelement.js , now im using this code but it has problem with firefox

```
[mejsvideo mp4="http://example.com/test.mp3" poster="http://example.com/test.jpg"preload="true" autoplay="true" width="620" height="300"]
```